# Recurrence relation that skips $n-1$?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, recursion

A difficult question I'm having problems with regarding recurrence relations and recurrence equations.

The question is as follows:

In how many different ways can I cover a 3xn checkberboard with 2x1 domino pieces?

**My problem:**

the formula I came up with seems to skip $n-1$. I'll show you. Here are the possible ways to start filling the tiles:

$\begin{pmatrix} a & a & ... \\ b & c & ... \\ b & c & ...\end{pmatrix}$

Or

$\begin{pmatrix} a & b & ... \\ a & b & ... \\ c & c & ... \end{pmatrix}$

Or

$\begin{pmatrix} a & a & ... \\ b & b & ... \\ c & c & ...\end{pmatrix}$

Do you see the problem? There is no way to fill just the first column. there is no dependence on n-1. If you were to ask me what is the recurrence equation, I'd say:

$f(n) = 3f(n-2)$

Could that be? That doesn't make sense really.

Comment: I would vote to close this as a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365/tiling-a-3-by-2n-rectangle-with-dominoes  I don't mean it as an insult-searching the site is quite difficult.  Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there are cases that you haven't covered, such as

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & a & e & e \\ b & c & c & f\\ b & d & d & f\end{pmatrix},$$ so your recursion isn't so simple. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365/tiling-a-3-by-2n-rectangle-with-dominoes) for more.

As you observed, we can't fill exactly one column with these dominoes, but we can say even more. We can't allow the matrix to have an odd number of columns *at all*, so in fact, the recursion **must** skip back to $n-2,$ rather than $n-1.$

Comment: Yes I just realized this as well. Now it just falls to how do I cover all of the cases

Comment: @CameronBuie:  It is possible to fill six or more without a block of two or four.  Take the matrix you give in your answer and add three horizontal dominoes, one to the right of $ee$ and two to the left of $ff$.  You can do this as many times as you want.

Comment: @Ross: D'oh! My thanks. Reconsidering what I'd thought to be a clever observation, so that I may add to my answer.

Comment: I dont understand your example Ross. You used the answer Cameron gave, but that matrix is a full 4 block, so you did use a full block of 4 to fill the block of 6. If I understood you correctly anyway.

Comment: @Oria: Not quite. Note that one of the dominoes was placed to the right of the $e$ domino. The other two were placed between $c$ and $f$ and between $d$ and $f.$

Comment: Ah yes I see...Well this is bad. We can keep doing that forever.

Comment: @Oria: Yep. As for the actual recursion, a similar question has been asked before [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365/tiling-a-3-by-2n-rectangle-with-dominoes). (Note that the $n$ in your problem is different from the $n$ in theirs.)