# Domino tiling on a 3 by N rectangle

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, recurrence-relations, tiling

The question is how to tile $3×N$ rectangle with $1×2$ domino.

I know exactly how to get the stuff below.(Assume that there is a g(x) which is an rectangle with one square on the latest row) [This link asked the same question, you can't look at it if you don't understand what I mean](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365/tiling-a-3-times-n-rectangle-with-dominoes)

$$f(0) = g(0) = 1$$

$$f(n) = f(n-1) + 2g(n-1)$$

$$g(n) = f(n) + g(n-1)$$

But how can I transfer these equations into $$f(n) = 4f(n-1) - f(n-2)?$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$f_{n+1}=f_n+2g_n$$ and
$$f_n=f_{n-1}+2g_{n-1}.$$
Thus, $$f_{n+1}-f_n=f_n-f_{n-1}+2f_n$$ or
$$f_n=4f_{n-1}-f_{n-2}$$
and we are done!