# Find the number of ways of tiling a $3\times n$ rectangular grid with $2\times 1$ dominoes

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, tiling

I'm trying to find the number of ways $(a_n)$ of tiling a $3\times n$ rectangular grid with $2\times 1$ dominoes, where rotation is allowed. I want to find a recurrence relation for $(a_n)$ and an explicit formula for it.

For $n=1$, this cannot be done. For $n=2$, this can be done in two ways (three vertical dominoes or two horizontal and one vertical). Already for $n=4$ the complexity rises considerably. And I don't have nearly enough data to even guess at a general formula to prove by induction, for example.

Comment: For $n=3$, the complexity is about the same as for $n=1$.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of /related to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365/tiling-a-3-times-2n-rectangle-with-dominoes?rq=1. Also see: http://oeis.org/A001835, relevant for the case which does not permit rotation.

Comment: I don't think recursion will work.  That is, as the number of columns changes from $n$ to $n+2$, you can not exclude the possibility that for $(n+2)$ a pattern exists that is not a continuation of a pattern used for $(n)$.

Comment: I would say that for $n=2$ it can be done in three ways, since there are two different places you can put the odd domino. (Also, I'd say $3\times n$ is three rows and $n$ columns, so $3\times2$ is three horizontals, or one horizontal and two veritcals.)

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A001835

Comment: Any thoughts on my comments, andrej?

Comment: Did you try following up any of the links given at the OEIS page? David Klarner and Jordan Pollack, Domino tilings of rectangles with fixed width, Disc. Math. 32 (1980) 45-52 looks promising. Also, 
R. J. Mathar, Paving Rectangular Regions with Rectangular Tiles: Tatami and Non-Tatami Tilings, arXiv:1311.6135 [math.CO], 2013, Table 2, and R. J. Mathar, Tilings of rectangular regions by rectangular tiles: Counts derived from transfer matrices, arXiv:1406.7788 (2014), eq. (4).  (continued)

Comment: And possibly Valcho Milchev and Tsvetelina Karamfilova, Domino tiling in grid - new dependence, arXiv:1707.09741 [math.HO], 2017, and also  Thotsaporn ”Aek” Thanatipanonda, Statistics of Domino Tilings on a Rectangular Board, Fibonacci Quart. 57 (2019), no. 5, 145-153. See p. 151, and maybe some others. It's really lazy to just write, "I did not really understand the content of the link you provided,"  without telling me where exactly you got stuck, and without putting in some effort to make full use of the OEIS page.

Comment: Not very nice, to change your question, after other users have made an effort to help you with it. Please change it back to the original version, and, if you have a new question, then post it as a new question.

Comment: Never mind, I did it for you.

Comment: I'm still waiting for more answers

Comment: Fine, but, while you're waiting, have you looked at those references I found for you?

Comment: I say, have you looked at those references????

Answer (score 1):

You can try to build a recursion with more terms by considering how many options there are to tile the right part of a "shape", and hope that it doesn't get too messy:

Given $a,b\in [0,2]$ with $a \geq b $ let $f_n(a,b)$ be the number of ways to cover a $3\times n$ grid with $a$ extra squares in the right of the bottom row and $b$ extra squares in the right of the middle row. By classifying by the orientation of the domino covering the top-right square we obtain:

$f_n(0,0) = f_{n-1}(1,1) + f_{n-2}(2,2)$

$f_n(1,0) = f_{n-1}(1,1)$ ( here note the bottom right tile must be covered horizontally).

$f_n(1,1) = f_{n}(0,0) + f_{n-1}(1,0)$ ( by checking both cases the bottom right tile can be covered).

$f_n(2,0) = f_n(0,0)$ (by checking how the bottom right tile must be covered).

$f_n(2,1) = f_{n-2}(2,1) =  0$ (just check wherever the right-most vertical domino appears, the stuff to the right of it cant be covered proper in one of the rows).

$f_n(2,2) = f_n(1,1)+f_n(2,0)$ ( by checking  how the middle right tile can be covered).

---

Hence we have three nice values: $f_n(0,0), f_n(1,1),f_n(2,2)$.

and recurrences:

$f_n(0,0) = f_{n-1}(1,1) + f_{n-2}(2,2)$

$f_n(1,1) = f_n(0,0) + f_{n-2}(1,1)$

$f_n(2,2) = f_n(1,1) + f_n(0,0)$

So it is already possible to get a nice $6\times 6$ matrix and just view this as a linear recurrence with that matrix.